# creating a model with name "import" is it reserved word in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, reserved-words

having all kind of strange stuff happening with a model and form named "import"
is this a reserved word in rails somehow? I could not find it in some old webposts on reserved words in rails.

EDIT:
Some code example to Illustrate, seem to be unable to pinpoint the problem

Works:

```
- @profile = Profile.new
  = form_for @profile, :method => :get,  :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f|
throws error # embed raw
```

Fails:

```
- @import = Import.new
  = form_for @import, :method => :get,  :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f|
```

With error:

```
undefined method `imports_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fe4e0369468>:0x007fe4e25410e0>
```

Comment: In your failing example, do you actually have a route for an  `ImportsController`?

Comment: It was a problem with naming my controller :( Searched for long time but its fixed now thx for efforts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it was incorrect naming of controller import model that caused this, I missed the S char in the filename

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, `import` is not a [reserved word](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_quick_guide.htm) in Ruby.

It is much more likely an issue with your specific codebase.